# MySQL/PHP - SELECT DISTINCT column based on another column with ORDER and LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table named **messages** that is as follows:

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
| id  | sender_id | receiver_id | ... |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
|   . |         . |           . | ... |
|   . |         . |           . | ... |
| 120 |        19 |          11 | ... |
| 121 |         1 |           3 | ... |
| 122 |         9 |          18 | ... |
| 123 |         2 |           1 | ... |
| 124 |         1 |          24 | ... |
| 125 |         3 |           1 | ... |
| 126 |         7 |           5 | ... |
| 127 |        24 |           1 | ... |
| 128 |        25 |           1 | ... |
| 129 |         1 |          25 | ... |
| 130 |         7 |           3 | ... |
| 131 |         3 |           5 | ... |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
```

How can I select the last 3 unique users that have communicated with User 1? 
In other words, how can I select:

- distinct sender_ids whose receiver_id is 1 **or** distinct receiver_ids whose sender_id is 1
- in descending order **and** limited to 3?

The result would look like this:

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
| id  | sender_id | receiver_id | ... |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
| 129 |         1 |          25 | ... |
| 127 |        24 |           1 | ... |
| 125 |         3 |           1 | ... |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
```

or simply:

```
+----+
| 25 |
| 24 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I did not see your distinct part of the question. Here you go:

```
SELECT id, sender_id, receiver_id FROM messages t1, 
 (SELECT max(id) maxid, if(sender_id=1,receiver_id,sender_id) other
  FROM messages WHERE sender_id=1 OR receiver_id=1 
  GROUP BY other ) t2 
WHERE t1.id=t2.maxid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Nice! Quite straightforward. With this approach, is it possible for for the output sender_ids/receiver_ids be in one column, e.g., user_id? And how can other columns be included in the output? Like: id, user_id, message, timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
    SELECT id,sender_id,receiver_id, IF(sender_id =1, receiver_id,sender_id) as t
  FROM `messages` where 1 IN (sender_id,receiver_id) GROUP by t  order by id desc
```

Sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/930445/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea why it throws the following error?

Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.messages.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
(https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT   MAX(id) Max_ID,
         CASE WHEN sender_id=1 THEN receiver_id 
              WHEN receiver_id=1 THEN sender_id END AS r_s_id
FROM     messages 
GROUP BY r_s_id HAVING r_s_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Max_ID DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

If you want to only return the sender/receiver id, you can turn it into a sub-query and simply select the column `r_s_id`:

```
SELECT r_s_id 
  FROM
(SELECT   MAX(id) Max_ID,
         CASE WHEN sender_id=1 THEN receiver_id 
              WHEN receiver_id=1 THEN sender_id END AS r_s_id
FROM     messages 
GROUP BY r_s_id HAVING r_s_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Max_ID DESC 
LIMIT 3) SQ;
```

Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mzGQreiFp5t6xBNEZFdqzc/1

Comment: Worked like a charm! And quite understandable. Nice how it outputs the id as Max_ID, and the sender_ids/receiver_ids as r_s_id. What if I want to include other columns in the output? Example: Max_ID, r_s_id, message, timestamp.

Comment: That's another thing to consider @amatek .. because you might need another sub-query to match the message and timestamp. I can help you with that but you need to build a full example schema (required table structures and a 10-20 rows of data sample) in db-fiddle. Once you've done that, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61947580/edit) to include the db-fiddle link. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, @tcadidot0 ... Your answer has helped me a lot with my ongoing project. I wish I would be able to contact you in the future.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT id, sender_id, receiver_id FROM messages WHERE sender_id=1 OR receiver_id=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3